# SQLMAP missing one or more core extensions ('gzip', 'ssl', 'sqlite3', 'zlib')

Tags: sqlmap

How to solve the following problem?

[16:49:39] [CRITICAL] missing one or more core extensions ('gzip', 'ssl', 'sqlite3', 'zlib') most likely because current version of Python has been built without appropriate dev packages

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, basically you need to install the dev packages of those extensions and then reinstall Python.

In my case I was missing the bz2 and I installed it using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev
```

Then I reinstalled python3 using:

```
pyenv install 3.8.0
```

And that solved the problem. In your case you'll need to install all those packages (and their dev counterparts) and reinstall Python.